# Plot 2 or more groups with multiple levels in ggplot2 aes(group)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function below:

```r
tidy_multi_normal <- function(.n = 50, .mean = c(-1,0,1), .sd = c(1), .num_sims = 2){
    
    n <- as.numeric(.n)
    mu <- as.numeric(.mean)
    std <- as.numeric(.sd)
    num_sims <- as.numeric(.num_sims)
    
    x <- seq(1, num_sims, 1)
    
    ps <- seq(-n, n-1, 2)
    qs <- seq(0, 1, (1/(n-1)))
    
    df <- expand_grid(
        sim_number = x,
        mu = mu,
        std = std
    )
    
    df <- df %>%
        mutate(sim_number = as.factor(sim_number)) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(sim_number, mu, std) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(x = list(1:n)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(y = list(stats::rnorm(n, mu, std))) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(d = list(density(unlist(y), n = n)[c("x","y")] %>%
                                   purrr::set_names("dx","dy") %>%
                                   dplyr::as_tibble())) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(p = list(stats::pnorm(ps, mu, std))) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(q = list(stats::qnorm(qs, mu, std))) %>%
        tidyr::unnest(cols = c(x, y, d, p, q)) %>%
        dplyr::ungroup() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dist_type = paste0("Gaussian: c(", mu, ", ", std, ")")) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dist_type = as.factor(dist_type)) %>%
        dplyr::select(
            sim_number, dist_type, dplyr::everything()
        ) %>%
        dplyr::arrange(sim_number, dist_type)
    
    return(df)
    
}
```

I call: `tn <- tidy_multi_normal(.num_sims = 3)`

Which gives the following:

```r
> tn %>% select(dist_type, sim_number, dx, dy)
# A tibble: 450 x 4
   dist_type          sim_number    dx       dy
   <fct>              <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -3.19 0.000433
 2 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -3.03 0.00144 
 3 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.87 0.00410 
 4 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.71 0.0102  
 5 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.55 0.0220  
 6 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.39 0.0417  
 7 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.23 0.0694  
 8 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -2.07 0.103   
 9 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -1.91 0.138   
10 Gaussian: c(-1, 1) 1          -1.75 0.169
```

What I want to do is group on the dist_type column and color by the sim_number. The following gives not what I expect:

```r
tn %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = dx, y = dy, group = dist_type, color = sim_number)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

I expect to be seeing three simulations for each dis_type.

Comment: How are you calling `tidy_multi_normal`? It's a function that you never use, nor do we know how `tn` is created.

Comment: I updated, thought I put how I create tn down

Comment: Note that we can have multiple columns inside one mutate.

Answer (score 2):

The `group=` is insufficient to break them apart, change that to `interaction(dist_type, sim_number)`:

```r
ggplot(tn, aes(x = dx, y = dy, group = interaction(dist_type, sim_number), color = sim_number)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

[image]